# HTML/CSS: Getting links styled like buttons to stack

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, hyperlink

I'm currently working on a simple project in HTML/CSS (Bootstrap). Very simply, I have the task of styling  links to look like buttons, and getting them to stack in a mobile view.

Requirements: buttons should be side-by-side on regular/desktop view, and should stack on top of each other in iPhone/Android devices.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anfperez/pen/joqoXG

Here's the code I have so far:

html

```
<a class="button-a" href="www.google">Link that looks like button</a>
<a class="button-b" href="www.amazon.com">Another link that looks like a button</a>
```

css (Bootstrap can be included)

```
.button-a, .button-b {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.button-a {
  background-color: blue
}

.button-b {
  background-color: red;
}
```

When I try viewing the code in a mobile view, the red button button ends up overlapping on top of the blue button since they're both links. How can I get the red button to clear the blue button? I can't use Bootstrap's btn-group in this case.

Comment: Side note: your href for the second link is "ahref".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Flexbox` inside a media query to stack the elements using `flex-direction: column`.

```css
.button-a, .button-b {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.button-a {
  background-color: blue
}

.button-b {
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="button-a" href="www.google">Link that looks like button</a>
  <a class="button-b" href="www.amazon.com">Another link that looks like a button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

....really? you can making a have behaviour of div, if you want them to stack, just make the button class having inline-block

```
.button-a, .button-b {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[Edited Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmyXjK)
This make the a link has the margin and padding behaviour like div. You just have to setting the width.. So if the media canvas shorter, the link will automatically stacking

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button-a, .button-b {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  display:block;
}

.button-a {
  background-color: blue
}

.button-b {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please also add some explanation because code-only answers are considered low-quality.